# GetVSTOObject returns Nothing

Tags: vb.net, vsto, excel-2007

as a workaround for the Locale bug in Office Interop I wanted to use VSTO but if I call

```
app.ActiveWorkbook.GetVstoObject()
```

then it returns nothing. I'm working from a .NET 2.0 Visual Basic Application project. This is not an add in or a special VSTO project. I have added the required Imports and References.

```
Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Caption = "Rapport"
app.Visible = True
app.Workbooks.Add()
Dim tmp As Object = app.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

Dim book As Workbook = app.ActiveWorkbook.GetVstoObject() 'Returns Nothing
```

This is a school project and it needs to be finished by the end of next week so any fast help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be "By Design".  The documentation for GetVStoObject states it will return `Nothing` in the case that the excel worksheet is a not a Visual Studio Tools For Office Excel Worksheet

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.getvstoobject.aspx

You're going to need to create an explicit Excel Worksheet Project in order to have this method return meaningful data .

Comment: agreed with Jared, this is by design.

Comment: This sucks, because I'm not allowed to do that. Guess I'll have to but up with the buggy Interop then.